# How does Star-Schema Design really work and how does the tables relate

Tags: sql, sas

How does a star schema really work I know you have different types of tables that is used to create the star. Like FCT, DM, SCD and JNK tables but I don't really understand how these tables interact and why it makes sense.
How does one dimension table connect to another? do they have to include data about the same subject to be in the same star? How does the data relate when multiple stars are in play?

The more I read about the star schema structure less I understand

Comment: FCT= fact, DM = dimension. SCD is a type of dimension. JNK is also a type of dimension. So really there's only two main types of tables: fact and dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my journey to understand star schema I have compiled some notes on the subject to answer my own question. The notes are inspired by some of the content in the book recommended by @NickW The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling, 3rd Edition https://amzn.eu/d/7TctCjL

A star schema is a type of database design that is used in data warehousing. It called a star schema because the diagram of the schema resembles a star, with a central fact table surrounded by a number of dimension tables.
The central fact table in a star schema contains the numeric measurements or facts for the business process being analyzed. For example, in a sales data warehouse, the fact table might contain sales data such as the date of the sale, the amount of the sale, and the product that was sold.
Dimension tables contain descriptive attributes that relate to the business process being analyzed. For example, in a sales data warehouse, dimension tables might include customer information, product information, and location information. Each dimension table has a one-to-many relationship with the fact table. Example, a single customer might make multiple sales, and each of those sales would be recorded in the fact table with a foreign key referencing the customer's record in the customer dimension table.
In a star schema, each dimension table is connected directly to the central fact table, and there are no relationships between dimension tables. This is what gives the schema its star-like shape.
When multiple stars are in play, the data can be related by linking the fact tables in each star through a common dimension table. For example, you might have a star schema for sales data and another star schema for inventory data. Both of these stars could be linked through a common product dimension table. This would allow you to analyze sales and inventory data together by joining the fact tables on the product dimension table.
Overall, the star schema is a useful tool for organizing and storing data in a data warehouse because it allows for fast querying and good performance. It is particularly well-suited for business intelligence and reporting applications where large amounts of data need to be analyzed quickly.

As an example:

Fact table: Sales

```
Sale ID (primary key)

Date

Customer ID (foreign key to Customer dimension table)

Product ID (foreign key to Product dimension table)

Quantity

Amount
```

Dimension table: Customer

```
Customer ID (primary key)

Name

Address

Phone
```

Dimension table: Product

```
Product ID (primary key)

Name

Category

Price
```

In this example, the fact table contains numeric measurements about sales, such as the date of the sale, the customer who made the sale, the product that was sold, and the quantity and amount of the sale. The customer and product dimension tables contain descriptive attributes about the customers and products, such as the customer's name and address, and the product's name, category, and price.
The star schema allows you to quickly query the data and analyze it in various ways. For example, you could use the schema to answer questions such as:
How much revenue was generated by each customer in a given time period?
What is the total quantity of a particular product that has been sold?
What is the average sale amount for a particular product category?
You also use the schema to join data from other sources, such as an inventory data warehouse, to perform more complex analysis. For example, you could use the schema to answer questions such as:
What is the sales revenue for a particular product in a given time period, compared to the quantity of that product in inventory during that same time period?
What is the sales revenue for each product category, compared to the total inventory value for that category?

I hope this helps someone who also has the issue of not understanding the concept of star schemas in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensional modelling is too big a topic to be covered in a forum like this. I would suggest you start by reading the "bible" on the topic: The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling, 3rd Edition https://amzn.eu/d/7TctCjL

Comment: Thank you for the recomendation I will that book